# Sum of multiple table row

Tags: laravel

How can i get sum of all these counts?

```
{{ DB::table('A')->count()}}
{{ DB::table('B')->count()}}
{{ DB::table('C')->count()}}
{{ DB::table('D')->count()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  // Your Tables Which You Know Them Counts
  $tables = ['A', 'B'];

  // Our Count Start From Zero
  $count = 0;

  // Count Each Table And Add Our Count
  foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $tableCount = DB::table($table)->count();
    $count += $tableCount;
  }

  // Display Count With dd()
  dd( $count );

  // Or Display In View
  return view('index', compact('count'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
{{ $a = DB::table('A')->count()}}
{{ $b = DB::table('B')->count()}}
{{ $c = DB::table('C')->count()}}
{{ $d = DB::table('D')->count()}}

{{ $sum = $a + $b + $c + $d }}
```

But you may want to send all these data from a controller method instead of doing it in a view.

Comment: `{{ DB::table('A')->count()+DB::table('B')->count()+ DB::table('C')->count()+DB::table('D')->count()}}`

Comment: Sure. Why not? :)